# Android SDK Update Issues

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

After updating to SDK version 21 and updating my support library and build tools my Life has been in total AWRY today. Cause, all my project wouldn't build cause R file is missing. I later got two projects fixed after 2hrs of just going around and replacing Jars to fix mismatchs mismatch and restarting and all, but didn't work for other projects. I then ran one of the projects and it kept on throwing **NULL POINTER EXCEPTION** where I was calling `getActionBar` and then I decided to comment it out. And there, I saw why. I couldn't see my ActionBar again when I ran the app. And then, I tried the second project and was getting **Could not find PODy.apk!** Now, I feel like dying already. And then came those errors from before again below you'll see the error I'm getting in the Android terminal. Any help would be appreciated. And If anyone knows where I can get AppCompat v20, I'll really be greatful.

```
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] /Users/mac/Documents/Eclipse/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD] 
[2014-10-24 19:57:24 - POD]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error messages you posted is most likely that the target SDK version of the appcompat library is set to `19` instead of `21`. The `Material` attributes do not exist in the API level 19, thus causing these errors.

You should change that (in Eclipse): Right click on the appcompat project > Properties > Android, and set the Project Build Target to Android 5.0.

Comment: I've done all that. I made sure every project has a target version of 21. Including appcompat

Comment: If you know where I can get v20, I'll be very greatful. I've projects that need to be attended too. I've googled around for it and couldn't find it. Thanks